# Using variables for shell script in C

Tags: c, bash, shell, sed

I have a shell script in C which is defined as

```
#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
sed 's/./& \
inserted text \
  /20' fileA.txt > fileB.txt \
"
```

When this shell script is run on terminal, it inserts the text `inserted text` in fileB.txt at offset 20. Now, I want this `20` `fileA.txt` and `fileB.txt` to be fetched from a variable.

How should I do that? I tried the following

```
#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
    sed 's/./& \
    inserted text \
      /$i' fileA.txt > fileB.txt \
    "
```

and in C before I run the above shell script, I run `system("i=20");` but then I get this error below

`sed: 1: "s/./& this comment has  ...": bad flag in substitute command: '$'`

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Not clear. If you want to have variable fields you have to compose the string in your code. How do you get the idea `sed` or the shell in general has access to internal state of your program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run `system()`, it starts up a fresh shell each time.  So the shell that `i=20` runs in is not the same shell that the `sed` command runs in.

Instead of `$i` in the script text, put `%d` there instead.  Then you can use it as a format string to sprintf which can format the command into a separate variable.

```
#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
    sed 's/./& \
    inserted text \
      /%d' fileA.txt > fileB.txt \
    "

char command[500];
sprintf(command, SHELLSCRIPT, 20);
system(command);
```

Comment: you beat me by 30s :)

Comment: @prabodhprakash That is where the result of the formatted string is placed.  Then you can pass that to `system`.

Comment: It essentially runs properly, but produce this extra line as output. Can this be prevented?

Answer (score 1):

how about you replace your script command

```
#define SHELLSCRIPT "\
    sed 's/./& \
    inserted text \
      /%d' %s > %s \
    "
```

and then you replace by your variables, before executing the command:

```
char cmd[100 +1];
sprintf(cmd, SHELLSCRIPT , 20, "file1", "file2");
system(cmd)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I would have marked this as correct, had this been thr first answer. Upvoted to show support.